# Is there anything wrong with "Relation between smoking and academic achievement"?

Tags: gerunds

Is it grammatically correct?
I'm not sure because smoking is verb and academic achievement is a noun.
If it's not what is the correct sentence?

Answer (score 1):

I would choose "relation*ship* between smoking and academic achievement."

Smoking is a gerund here, an -ing verb acting as a noun to describe the act of doing something, so comparing it to "academic achievement" is appropriate.  As mentioned by tunny, this is a sentence fragment as it stands, not a complete sentence.

"The relationship between smoking and academic achievement is..."

Answer (score 0):

It is not a complete sentence, but it is correct as  headline or part of a sentence. Smoking is a *gerund*; gerunds are parts of the verb which have many of the properties of a noun.

Comment: so you're saying that it is correct?

Comment: @ storm Rage. I am just adding that to the answer.